# Perl Regular expression for string with \g throws error

Tags: regex, perl

```
$warning_line="C:\PGMFile\VERSION\ghunt\ol.txt";
$newWarning="C:\PGMFile\VERSION\ghunt\ol.txt";
if ($warning_line =~  $newWarning)
{           
    some logic
}
```

throws error

```
Reference to invalid group 0 in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/"C:\PGMFile\VERSION\g <-- HERE hunt\ol.txt", line 3
```

Comment: between double quotes backslah is an escape character, here can be fixed with single quotes.
also it as a special meaning when used in a regex  `\g` for backreference for example `\g{-1}`. see [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre)

Comment: A good question might be "why are you trying to compare two file paths with a regex"?

Comment: Indeed `eq` or `ne` functions seem more appropriate

Comment: The code you posted doesn't produce the error you claim it does; it doesn't even compile!!!

Answer (score 1):

Backslash must be doubled beetwen double quotes and doubled in a regexep expression so following changes should fix.

```
# qq for double quotes
$newWarning = qq(C:\\\\PGMFile\\\\VERSION\\\\ghunt\\\\ol.txt)
```

otherwise using quotemeta or `\Q` ... `\E`

```
# q for single quotes
$newWarning = quotemeta( q(C:\PGMFile\VERSION\ghunt\ol.txt) )
```

Note: even within single quotes backslash is an escape character because it can escape the final quote delimiter so a double backslash represents a single backslash.

OR

```
if ($warning_line =~  /\Q$newWarning\E/)
```

Comment: In a single quoted string, backslash is *only* an escape character when it is in front of the string delimiter , which *may* be `'`, but with `q()`, you can change that delimiter to almost anything.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, these don't do what you think

```perl
$warning_line="C:\PGMFile\VERSION\ghunt\ol.txt";
$newWarning="C:\PGMFile\VERSION\ghunt\ol.txt";
```

`\` has a special meaning in double-quoted strings. What you have there doesn't even compile as a result.

```
$ perl -M5.010 -we'
   $warning_line = "C:\PGMFile\VERSION\ghunt\ol.txt";
   say $warning_line;
'
Unrecognized escape \P passed through at -e line 2.
Unrecognized escape \V passed through at -e line 2.
Unrecognized escape \g passed through at -e line 2.
Missing braces on \o{} at -e line 2, within string
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

What you want:

```perl
my $warning_line = "C:\\PGMFile\\VERSION\\ghunt\\ol.txt";
my $newWarning   = "C:\\PGMFile\\VERSION\\ghunt\\ol.txt";
```

`"C:\\PGMFile\\VERSION\\ghunt\\ol.txt"` produces the string `C:\PGMFile\VERSION\ghunt\ol.txt`.

---

Secondly, now that we got the string `C:\PGMFile\VERSION\ghunt\ol.txt` in the variables, there's a second issue. `\` is special in regex patterns. You can use `quotemeta` or `\Q..\E` to solve that.

```perl
# If $warning_line contains $newWarning
if ($warning_line =~ /\Q$newWarning\E/) {   # Trailing \E can be omitted.
   ...
}
```

```perl
# If $warning_line is equal to $newWarning
if ($warning_line =~ /^\Q$newWarning\E\z/) {
   ...
}
```

```perl
# If $warning_line is equal to $newWarning
if ($warning_line eq $newWarning) {
   ...
}
```